# Liquibase duplicate identifiers using inclueAll tag

Tags: include, duplicates, identifier, liquibase

I'm new to liquibase and trying to setup a working solution for our software. At the moment i'm struggling with the 'includeAll' tag for the master changelog.

If i'm using includeAll it allways says:

Validation Error:
    1 change sets had duplicate identifiers
        install/data/changelog-data.xml::1::wild.a
Liquibase 'validate' Successful

The whole files to reproduce are included in the database.zip which can be downloaded here:
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B8W-n_j7omQ4UUhzQjdrdnlMdk0/edit?usp=sharing

You only have to modify liquibase.properties.

The curious thing is that the following line work:

```
<include relativeToChangelogFile="true" file="install/data/changelog-data.xml"/>
```

While this line won't work:

```
<includeAll relativeToChangelogFile="true" path="install/data/"/>
```

The question is how to use includeAll to work without having duplicate identifiers.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I ran your example files on a derby db and I don't get the duplicate error. Neither way. Not with include but also not with includeAll. What DB are your running against and what version of liquibase are you using? Are you on windows?

Comment: Liquibase Version: 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT / Windows 7 x64 (SP1) / Oracle 11.2.0 Enterprise - Thanks in advance

Comment: There is an official version 3.0.0. You could try with that version instead of the SNAPSHOT. Other then that, I'm sorry I can't help. Can't reproduce your problem in my environment and just by looking at those two changeset files I can tell where the problem could be. It should work the way you use it...

Comment: The bad thing is that it is the official version 3.0.0. Even the today released version is 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT. I hope the support can tell my why this is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug in 3.0.0 that has been fixed in 3.0.2.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Will wait for 3.0.2 to try it again.